# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version from API response while running using jmeter

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter

When I try to run an API for pressure testing using JMeter, I am getting this Java exeption:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

I have tried changing the SSL version in the JMeter properties file, but I still see same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to determine the reason of the problem, it can be done by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

after JMeter restart look at the stdout and inspect which protocol(s) and cipher suite(s) are being used for the SSL handshake.

Depending on the outcome you may need to amend `https.default.protocol` and/or `https.socket.protocols` in *user.properties* file. If you're still at JDK 8 you might need to download [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html)

References:

- [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: i am new to jmeter and these procol can you guide me steps by steps thank you